# Filters and surjectivity of functions

Tags: general-topology, filters

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter on $Y$
>   and for all $F \in \mathcal{F}: F \cap f(X) \neq \emptyset$. Then,
>   $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \operatorname{stack} [f(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})]$ and if $f$ is
>   surjective, then $\mathcal{F} = f(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$

**My attempt**:

Let $F \in \mathcal{F}$, then $F \supseteq f(f^{-1}(F)) \in f(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))$. Hence, $F \in \operatorname{stack}[f(f^{-1} (\mathcal{F}))]$. This shows that the inclusion is true.

If $f$ is surjective, then it is trivial that $\mathcal{F} = f(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))$, since for any $F$, $f(f^{-1}(F)) = F$.

Where did I go wrong? I never used that $\mathcal{F}$ was a filter, or that $F \cap f(X) \neq \emptyset$ (the last condition is irrelevant if $f$ is surjective though)

Comment: How do you prove that the empty set is not in the induced filter?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: When you look at $f^{-1}(\cal F)$, how do you know that the empty set is not there?

Comment: How is that relevant? The statement does not ask to prove that it is a filter.

Comment: Okay, I guess I should have first asked what is $\operatorname{stack}_f$... :)

Comment: For a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets, $stack \mathcal{B}:= \{A \subseteq X \mid \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: B \subseteq A\}$. Maybe I was a bit too lazy but I should have written $stack(f(f^{-1}( \mathcal{F})))$.

Comment: You should be even less lazy than that and write `\operatorname{stack}` as well. :)

Comment: Ah that's the way you write it neatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is used to ensure that for a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ the set $f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}] = \{f^{-1}[F] : F \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is actually a filter on $X$. It's used for the non-triviality axiom $\emptyset \notin  f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$.

For a filter $\mathcal{B}$ on $X$ we define $f[\mathcal{B}] = \{f[B]: B \in \mathcal{B}\}$, and this is a filterbase on $Y$, so that $\operatorname{stack}(f[\mathcal{B}])$ is a filter on $Y$.

Indeed, the first inclusion is trivial: if $F \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f[f^{-1}[F]] \in f[f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]]$ and as $f[f^{-1}[F]] \subseteq F$ by definition, indeed $F \in \operatorname{stack}(f[f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]])$, and so $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \operatorname{stack}(f[f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]])$. No more to it than that.

And if $F$ is surjective, we always have $f[f^{-1}[F]] = F$ which shows the reverse inclusion as filters are closed under supersets: $A \in \operatorname{stack}(f[f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]])$ means there is some $F \in \mathcal{F}$ with $f[f^{-1}[F]] \subseteq A$ so $F \subseteq A$ and so $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Hence $\mathcal{F} \supseteq \operatorname{stack}(f[f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]])$ and equality. We indeed use little of the filter axioms.

Comment: But I think for what I showed there really is no need to use the liested condition or filter axioms? Or where did I go wrong? I know that I need tjat condition to know the preimage will be a filterbasis on X, but I don't seem to need that anywhere.

Comment: @Math_QED I only used the superset axiom. No others. The rest are just general facts needed to define inverse and forward images of filters.

Comment: Yes, but I need to show that $f(f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})) = \mathcal{F}$, given that $f$ is surjective. You showed something else. It looks like I don't neef that axiom for that.

Comment: @Math_QED Well, what's the problem if you don't need it? $\operatorname{stack}(f[])$ and $f^{-1}[]$ are forward and backward transforms from certain filters on $Y$ to filters on $X$ and back. For surjective $f$ they're inverses. That's the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: Why would the exercice give the conditions if they aren't necessary? This seems rather confusing, hence my question.

Comment: @Math_QED the intersection with $f[X]$ condition is needed make $f^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$ well-defined at all.

Comment: That's needed to make sure it is a filter, but I don't need that in the proof. I surely can write down the preimage of a collection, whether it is empty or not.

Comment: @Math_QED It’s not needed in the proof, but it’s a contextual given.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!